# Search within tags with BeautifulSoup Python

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I wanted to search within the  tag:

```
<div id="cmeProductSlatePaginiationTop" class="cmePaginiation">
   <ul>
      <li class="disabled">
      <li class="active">
      <li class="away-1">
      <li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Basically, I want to count the number of occurunces of `<li ..>` in this div. However, when I used beautifulsoup, I can't get the tags in between the `div`

```
    soup = BeautifulSoup(resp)
    tags = soup.find('div', attrs = {'class' : 'cmePaginiation'})
    print tags
```

`>>> <div id="cmeProductSlatePaginiationTop" class="cmePaginiation">&nbsp;</div>`

Is there a way to count the number of instances of `li` (In this example 4)?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Use `find_all`:

```
div = soup.find('div', id='cmeProductSlatePaginiationTop')
lis = div.find_all('li')
num_lis = len(lis)
```

Comment: the contents in `div` is still this: `<div id="cmeProductSlatePaginiationTop" class="cmePaginiation">&nbsp;</div>` So I can't find any `li`

Comment: @JamesHallen: Is that your actual HTML, or is this what you see with a DOM inspector?

Comment: @JamesHallen: It works just fine for me. Are you *sure* that's the HTML that you're actually working with?

Comment: This is the HTML I'm using: `http://www.cmegroup.com/trading/products/#sortField=oi&sortAsc=false&venues=3&page=1&cleared=1&group=7`

Comment: @JamesHallen: View the source of that webpage. That's the actual HTML. The other elements are being loaded with JS.

Comment: So instead of looking for the `div` in the actual HTMl, I should search for it in as one of the GET methods in the JS?

Comment: @JamesHallen: The HTML that you're looking for is generated with JavaScript. It's not actually in the source code. If you look at what the JS loads in order to generate the HTML, you'll find a nice JSON API: http://www.cmegroup.com/CmeWS/mvc/ProductSlate/V1/List/500/1?sortField=oi&sortAsc=false&venues=3&p%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bage=1&cleared=1&group=7&r=2vBJ9zJR

Comment: Doesn't that give me the information in the table on that site? I want to count the number of pages which carry such tables (2 in this case).

Comment: @JamesHallen, at the end of the JSON document mentioned by Blender you will find a "pageTotal":2 key.

Comment: @Blender What if there are many `div ` tags and I want to do the same for all of them ?

Answer (score 4):

About 12 months too late. But, anyways, here is the solution:

`soup.find_all` returns a list of tags, even in the case there is only one tag.

Change the code to the following:

```py
div = soup.find('div', id='cmeProductSlatePaginiationTop')
lis = div[0].find_all('li')
num_lis = len(lis)`
```